# What is the minimum information you would expect on a basketball scoreboard?

Tags: basketball

I'm building a software scoreboard for basketball. I want to start with the absolute minimum feature set. What would that be? What are the the things that you would absolutely expect to see on a scoreboard?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want something that adheres to rules for displaying score information or are you polling for what most people want/expect?

Comment: The latter. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, much clearer, though unfortunately that makes it definitely off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree with @Nij. I would say that this question is on-topic.

Comment: Having something objective to refer to, sure. Asking what any random group would expect with no additional support or reference, the definition of a(n off-topic) poll.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Coach-D's response, don't forget the time remaining and the half/quarter which you are in.

> Score, timeoutes, fouls, bonus situation is the minimum.

Comment: This is a good addition.  I was just going bare minimum.   For rec basketball leagues we have the little rectangle scoretable display board and my answers choices are on there.   Never thought about the quarter/half for minimum stuff since it is just two 20 min halves.

Answer (score 2):

Score, timeoutes, fouls, bonus situation is the minimum.